# Adding padding without affecting other menu items

Tags: css, wordpress

When I use the following CSS, I go from the output of the image at the top to the image at the bottom:

```
.menu-border  {
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 30px 0px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

[image]

The purpose is to have a larger hover area for the mega menu, otherwise the mega menu disappears when the mouse is between the ''Assessment'' menu and the mega menu box. However, when my padding is at 30px, all the menu items shift higher up. What would I need to add to keep this large box (the edges will be white - I put black so it is easier to see now) without affecting the rest of the menu?

edit1: the menu is generated from the pearl theme for wordpress. The .menu-border is an added css class for the ''assessment'' menu.

Comment: Welcome. please add your code.

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow Guy, with your question, please add the html structure so people can help you solve your exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for adding some code, Guy :)

Answer (score 0):

If we could get a working snippet it would be easier to help.

[image]

Also, there are two menus in your capture. I guess that adding the code it's the second one. Looks you're missing `vertical-align` property

```
.menu-border  {
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   padding: 30px 0px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you're exactly looking for but have a crack at this CSS that's using the `inline-block` property -

```
.menu-border  {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 30px 0px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Further reading on `CSS inline-block`
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. As you can see on the top picture, with a header padding of 5 px, every element is on a single line. However when I add a padding of 30 px on my box, it shifts all other element. The purpose of this box is simply to allow seeing the menu from Assessment without putting the cursor exactly on the text, but anywhere inside the box.

Answer (score 0):

If someone ever face that problem, the solution was to replace my code with this

```
body .stm-header .stm-navigation__default > ul > li > a {
padding: 30px 30px;
}
```